# Setting language in datepicker?

Tags: html, datepicker

I'm creating an html form with a datepicker field. I'd like to force the names of the months to appear in french, regardless of the user's browser settings. Is there a way to do this?

The html code I have is:

```
<input type="date" name="closedate">
```

I found a webpage that suggested adding a language to the field, but it seems to have no effect.

```
<input type="date" name="closedate" lang="fr">
```

I am not using a framework. It's just plain html.

Comment: Set the page language to french in the HTML tag?

Comment: "datepicker field" meaning a `date` type input, or a custom JS date-picker? If the latter, please let us know which. And either way it would be good to include more info in the question.

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Answer (score 0):

The most effective method seems to be setting an element's `translate` attribute to `no` and adding the class `notranslate`:

```
<html lang="fr">
  <div>
    Bonjour
  </div>
  <div translate="no" class="notranslate">
    Bonjour
  </div>
</html>
```

Now the latter `<div>` content should not be translated.

As your native language is French, here is a duplicate of the above in English, which Chrome should try to translate:

```
<html lang="en">
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
  <div translate="no" class="notranslate">
    Hello
  </div>
</html>
```

**To test this code**, you may have to save the code in a separate html file, and open it in Chrome, then said "Yes" to translating the page.

`translate="no"` appears to be the officially recommended method (*references: [1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#the-translate-attribute), [2](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-translate-flag)*), although did not seem to be effective on its own. Adding the `class="notranslate"` was what allowed this to work in my testing. As of now, Google translate seems to recognize this class, and will not translate within a `class="notranslate"` element. I could only find various articles on it though (*references: [1](https://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-disable-google-translate-from-translating-specific-words-or-content-blocks/), [2](https://ncoughlin.com/disable-google-translate-specific-page-paragraph/)*), no official documentation.

Comment: This seems to be related to translating the text in a webpage, but I'm looking for information on translating the text in the datepicker form element. Also, I'm hoping to do this in a way that doesn't need to use Google Translate.